# Cherrypy gives an error when using nltk (natural language tool kit)

Tags: python, nltk

I have installed an Apache server on a mac with cherrypy as my web framework.I intend to expose certain services involving nltk. And I get a 500 internal error on doing the same. Searches on the internet explain **"AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'word'"** as circular dependency  issue.I suspect version difference in system python and nltk.

I am new to Python and my debugging skills are really poor.Kindly help

```
import cherrypy
import nltk

class HelloWorld :
    def index(self) :
        return "Hello world !"
    index.exposed=True

    def printHappy(self,age) :
        return age
    printHappy.exposed=True

    def fNouns(self,string):
        text = nltk.word.tokenize(string)
        nounTag=nltk.pos_Tag(text)
        return  nounTag
    fNouns.exposed=True
```

cherrypy.quickstart(HelloWorld())

When I try to access it using `http://localhost:8080/fNouns/hey` , I get the following error
( However `http://localhost:8080/printHappy/1234` works!!)

```
500 Internal Server Error
```

The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cprequest.py", line 656, in respond
    response.body = self.handler()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/lib/encoding.py", line 188, in __call__
    self.body = self.oldhandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/CherryPy-3.2.2-py2.7.egg/cherrypy/_cpdispatch.py", line 34, in __call__
    return self.callable(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
  File "hello.py", line 14, in fNouns
    text = nltk.word.tokenize(string)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'word'
```

Comment: You need to `import nltk.word`.

Comment: Thanks Blender.Still doesn't solve.On the python terminal ,I can import nltk but I get this :Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    import nltk.word
ImportError: No module named word       if I use import nltk.word

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got the wrong function name. `nltk.word.tokenize` is actually called `nltk.word_tokenize`. You use it like so:

```
In [1]: from nltk import word_tokenize

In [2]: word_tokenize('i like cats and dogs')
Out[2]: ['i', 'like', 'cats', 'and', 'dogs']
```

If you use the wrong name you get the error you got:

```
In [3]: import nltk

In [4]: nltk.word.tokenize('i like cats and dogs')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/<ipython-input-4-a0785dff62d6> in <module>()
----> 1 nltk.word.tokenize('i like cats and dogs')

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'word'
```

Comment: Thanks mbatchkarov.It worked.Also it was pos_tag and not pos_Tag.Didn't really suspect this because the python console didn't throw up a problem when I used word.tokenize.Really appreciate your help.